# Is there a way to use a function to automate the task of writing row one by one with xlsxwriter write_row()?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am using the below code (from xlsxwriter module) to write each row from a dataframe to specific position in an excel file. Is there a way to put these repetitive codes into a function?

In this example, I have 22 rows in my dataframe, but there will be more or less rows in the next month, so I have to hard coded the position line by line as below. Any suggestion for automation these would be highly appericated.

```
max_len = df.shape[0] # There are 22 rows this month but will be more or less next month. I am hoping to use this as the ending position in a loop
worksheet.write_row('BA27',df.iloc[0,0:10])
worksheet.write_row('BA28',df.iloc[1,0:10])
worksheet.write_row('BA29',df.iloc[2,0:10])
worksheet.write_row('BA30',df.iloc[3,0:10])
worksheet.write_row('BA31',df.iloc[4,0:10])
worksheet.write_row('BA32',df.iloc[5,0:10])
worksheet.write_row('BA33',df.iloc[6,0:10])
######## more code to the line 22 #######
worksheet.write_row('BA48',df.iloc[21,0:10])
```

Comment: Where does the 'BA27',  'BA28', 'BA29' ........ come from?

Comment: Is it a fixed position I specified in the excel worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the BA column is fixed, you can do a for loop for that.
`for x in range(0,max_len): worksheet.write_row('BA'+str(27+x),df.iloc[x,0:10])`

Comment: Great. This works very well. Thanks a lot.